# Git clone stuck on receiving objects

Tags: git, github, gitlab, clone

When I am trying to clone a repository, I get to this point:
[image]

My OS: Windows 10 Enterprise. Could somebody help me to resolve this, please?

Comment: I had to reinstall Git for Windows to make it work on my system.

Answer (score 1):

May be try http or  ssh.but first its helpful if you start it again.